# Move differences of two branches into a third branch

Tags: git, github

I acidentally branched off my organisations 'staging' branch. I've merged my changes into staging from the feature branched I previously branched off staging with so its now in staging.

They now want it in develop, I can't merge the feature branch into develop as staging and develop are way different. What's the easiest way? Faster the better, atm I'm copy + pasting.

Comment: You can cherry pick the commits. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick might help

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to merge `feature` in `develop` but excluding changes that are not meant to be in `develop`. I think the best solution is to [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)  your commit with the changes that you want to merge into `develop`, this way you avoid merging something else into it:

```
git cherry-pick commitSha
```

Hope this help.

P.S.: One way to avoid these situations is always depart from `develop` and if you need changes to pass into `staging` you make a PR to it (Once you validate that all changes on `develop` are good to go).

Comment: `commitSha` being what? I thought it was `git cherry-pick develop` develop being the branch your moving your changes to?

Comment: `git cherry-pick B` takes the last commit from branch `B`

Comment: `commitSha` means de SHA (The unique identifier of the commit) of the commit that you want to do the `cherry-pick` on, I mean the commit with the changes that you want to move to `develop`.